# grep regex to find emails of a certain tld

Tags: regex, grep

I'd like to run a grep command that searches a text file and should match email address with a certain tld.

Example, if the text file contains the following lines

```
tom@google.com
mark@google.com
tom.comber@google.cz
```

And I'm searching for the `.com` tld emails:

It should match `tom@google.com` and `mark@google.com` but not `tom.comber@google.cz`

I'm currently using the follow grep command, which matches pretty much every string that contains a .com. I want it to match specifically the tld of the domain

```
grep -rnwi "/Users/Me/Desktop/Folder/" -e ".com"
```

EDIT

`grep -rnwi '@.+\.com$' "/Users/Me/Desktop/Folder/"` matches nothing.  but `grep -rnwi "/Users/Me/Desktop/Folder/" -e "hotmail.com"` matches plenty. I don't want just hotmail.com but all .com emails

EDIT2, this seem to match nothing either. is it because I'm searching in multiple text files in a folder?

```
 grep -rnwi '@.\+\.com$' "/Users/Me/Desktop/Folder/"
```

EDIT3: wasn't totally clear. There are characters after the `.tld` extension so I had to leave off the trailing `$`. That works.

Comment: add a `$` at the end of your pattern (and escape the dot with a backslash or a character class.) I.e: `-e "[.]com$"`

Comment: @stef, `-w` option is creating issue.. any reason you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
grep '@.\+\.com$' file.txt
```

- `@.\+` matches a `@` followed by one or more characters
- `\.com$` matches literal `.com` at the end

to do the same for other TLDs, replace `com` at the end with that TLD.

Comment: I would use simply `@.+\.com$`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thats more robust in this case, edited, thanks.

Comment: @stef No, you need to escape `+` as it is a ERE token, not BRE. See my answer. Do `grep '@.\+\.com$'`

Comment: Hey, I guess I wasn't totally clear. There's more characters right after the .tld. So your regex worked once I left off the trailing $. Answer accepted, thanks!